# Any working tutorials for Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, authentication

I've been trying to build my first rails app and have gotten stuck on the issue of user authentication.  I've found a number of tutorials for using various plug-ins to do this, but so far every single one of them is out-dated, and as a result, broken!

From what I've read, I think Authlogic may be the best fit for me, and I've tried two things:

1) Going through Railscast, episode #160 (which is a tutorial for setting it up)
2) Using Ryan B's nifty_authentication gem with the --authlogic tag

In both cases, I get the following error as soon as I try to do anything with a user:

> undefined local variable or method `acts_as_authentic' for #

I believe this is from the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

I'm sure I've installed the authlogic gem, and I've added

```
config.gem "authlogic"
```

to my environment.rb

Any ideas about what's wrong?  Anybody know of a complete and *up to date* tutorial for adding user authentication?

Edit:
I'm running Ruby v. 1.8.6 and rails v. 2.3.5

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing the gem?  I've made this mistake before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one thing that Ryan Bates in the RailsCasts episode doesn't talk about is about creating sessions table in your database. Type `rake db:sessions:create` in the console and run the migration `rake db:migrate`. Also like ghoppe says run `rake gems:install` after installing the gem. That is a requisite.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example app with a step-by-step guide - it's from last year but should still be mostly if not entirely accurate:

[authlogic_example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example)

Comment: This is really a great tutorial that fig-gnuton has linked to. Follow this step-by-step and you will have a good understanding of how things work.

Comment: That *is* one of the tutorials I tried following, which ended in errors!

Answer (score 2):

Since you added that line to your environment.rb, have you tried `rake gems:install` to ensure the gem is installed and working correctly?

Also, what version of Ruby? What version of Rails? Have you tried running `gem environment` and `gem list` to make sure they're installed and running from the right place?

Comment: Yes, I used gem list to make sure it was installed.  That's probably something the tutorials should have, though!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use authlogic as a plugin, with:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git
```

It also helps to look at a projects that uses authlogic as authentication module, like the fat_free_crm project, have a look at user.rb [there](http://github.com/michaeldv/fat_free_crm/blob/master/app/models/user.rb)

Last but not least, there is an active mailing list:

[authlogic mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/authlogic/topics)

Becoming popular is also the devise gem. Here you can add authentication with script/generate devise and you will have some views for login as well.

Answer (score 0):

I forked that [authlogic_example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) and added activity_tracker, authlogic, paperclip for user profile images, declarative_authorization, and user to user messages.

http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_cucumber_rspec_example